Both training and validation DFL_loss are zero
I am currently working on detecting occluded objects in realtime using the YOLO v8 algorithm. To improve the accuracy of my detections, I have implemented a CBAM attention module and updated the traditional loss function from IoU to EIoU. Additionally, I am using soft_nms, which utilizes EIoU instead of IoU. To further enhance the robustness of my model, I have also incorporated data augmentations such as mosaic.
But I am having a couple of questions,

During the customized model training, both train and val dfl_loss values are zero. Can you help me figure out why?

Test results (graphs)

Furthermore, I tried to add CBAM modules to the architecture and included the CBAM layer in the parse_model() function. However, this approach resulted in some errors. Could you please provide me with some guidance on how to resolve this issue?

Customized architecture
How I add the CBAM to the parse_model() function
The error I am getting

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
